# Subscribe function not call if I call Array.find() in it in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription, behaviorsubject

I am really new to Typescript and web development. I'm finding a strange thing when I subscribe to an event and cannot find solution for it.
I have a service with a `BehaviorSubject` which holds a `carId` in it. I have a page where there is a list of ids, and if I click on an id, then it calls `setCarId`. So far everything is working fine.

This is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
   private carId = new BehaviorSubject("");
   setCarId(carId: string) {
      this.carId.next(carId);
   } 
   getCarId(): Observable<string> {
     return this.carId.asObservable();
   }
```

And I have another service, where I subscribe to changes on `carId`. In this I have a car object and I want to get that car from my array of cars for which the id is in my `BehaviorSubject`. I get the car that I need, with an `array.find` method like in my code, and it's working properly, BUT NOT for subscribe. I don't know why, but with this line `this.car = this.cars.find(car => car.carId == carId)` the subscribe method doesn't get called, but without that line it works properly.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  subscription: Subscription;
  car: Car;
  cars: Array<Car>;

  constructor(private carService: CarService){
    this.subscription.getCarId().subscribe(carId=> {
       console.log('DO SOMETHING') //


       //with this row NOT working, without this row working
       this.car = this.cars.find(car => car.carId == carId) 
    });

... //MORE CODE
```

I don't know how why this is happening and how to solve it, so please help me.

Comment: this.cars is undefined?

Comment: no, it has values just I don't copy all of my code here

Comment: Check the dev-Tools in your browser, i think you are missing some ";" there, so depending of your tsconfig.json the typesctript doesn´t gets compiled into proper JS or the emitted JS just stops intepreting after the syntax-error:

`console.log('DO SOMETHING');
this.car = this.cars.find(car => car.carId == carId);`

Comment: I don't have the solution, but I find an other possibility of the reason of the fault, that my Car objects has a User object attribute, and maybe it can't transpiled to JS proper, as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I don't know the reason of why, but in subscribe method I couldn't use any methods of array, so for example console.log(this.cars.length) also didn't work, not just this.cars.find. However console.log(this.cars) write out correctly the array. Anyway the solution is that I initialized the cars array with an empty array like here.

```
 cars:Array<Car>=[];
```

and after this everything worked correctly. If someone can explain me the reason of this, that would be great and thank you all of your helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

The subscription works fine but there are some problems in your code.

First of all the list of cars is undefined so it won't find the car in your list.

Second, you try to call the getCarId method on this.subscription but this.discription does not have that method, CarService does.

If you initialize your cars array in MyService like this, it will work fine.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

subscription: Subscription;
car: any;
cars: Array<any> = [{carId: "1"}, {carId: "2"}];

    constructor(private carService: CarService){
        this.carService.getCarId().subscribe(carId=> {
            console.log('DO SOMETHING') //

            //with this row NOT working, without this row working
            this.car = this.cars.find(car => car.carId === carId) 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: no, cars has value, just I didn't copy all of my code. I added values in an other function. I checked it with console.log(this.cars)

Comment: Anyway I checked your basic solution, and you are right, that subscription work fine. So I go forward, and i think, the reason of the problem can be that my Car objects has an other User object as its attribute.